# A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. when use sqlalias and try to connect sql server

Tags: 2013, asp.net, sql-server, iis, sql-server-2012

i have an asp.net web application that connected to sql server 2012 from a server ( windows server 2012 R2) its a fresh installed server and installed oracle 32 bit client . its SharePoint wfe server.

and in this server i configured SQL ALIAS  and below is the connection string

```
<add name="countryConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=xyz_SPSQL;Initial Catalog=country;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

when this application try to get data fro country db i get this error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

[image]

Her after that i added 64 bit sql alias and got new error when i try to get data fro sql server

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ALIAS which can be configured - for 32 and 64 bit. Make sure you have both and try again.

Comment: sharepoint which version it use 32 or 64 ? and in asp.net application s application pool  i enabled 32 bit and it running on asp.net version 2.0